# Shrew Soft VPN Client: Route Metric

Tags: client, settings, profile, vpn, metric

After connecting to the business network I have no internet access.

`route print` shows:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.132.222  192.168.132.166    121
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0          On-link     10.100.10.26     31
<... snip ...>
```

Through these commands:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.132.222

route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.132.222 metric 1
```

I am able to then access both internet AND the business network.

I am wondering: Is there a way to define that via Shrew Settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shrew Soft VPN Acess Manager>Edit>Properties>Policy>Select(Maintain Persistent Security Assosiacations),Add(10.0.0.0,/255.0.0.0)

Answer (score 8):

The answer given by user416930 is correct, but a little unclear, so here it is spelled out a little better.

1. In Shrew Soft VPN Access Manager, go to Edit > Properties > Policy > Select.
2. Uncheck "Obtain Topology Automatically or Tunnel All".
3. Click "Add".  Add the network used by your VPN.

If you are unclear what VPN your network is using:

1. Open command prompt and type "ipconfig /all".
2. Look for the entry with "Screw Soft Virtual Adapter".

Comment: thanks man, you made my day after many days of several unsuccesfull tests!

Comment: HI! What if `ipconfig /all` shows always a different IP address? (after each connection-disconnection from the VPN)

Comment: Hi, figured it out. Just add the proper mask.